# Теряются пробелы в начале или в конце строки при выводе из базы в html

Tags: php, html

В базе имеются значения, которые могут начинаться с пробела или заканчиваться на него. Когда вывожу данные из базы в html:

`<table>
<tr><td contenteditable="true"> $string </td><tr>
</table>`, эти пробелы теряются (будто применили `trim($string)`).

`contenteditable="true"` в данном случае позволяет поставить курсор и исправить значение в `<td>`, будто это `input[type=text]`.

Как сделать так, чтобы пробелы в начале или в конце не терялись? Спасибо!

Comment: Что за база, как сохраняете, при сохранении пробел есть, перед выводом контента пробел есть, используете чистый скуль или это cms/фреймворк,pdo? И другие вопросы из этой серии)

Comment: str_replace(" ", "&nbsp",$text);

Comment: @Taarim, база mysql, сохраняю пока в phpmyadmin, пробел при сохранении есть и потом в базе при просмотре он есть, чистый php...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пробелы и переносы в конце строк в HTML обрезаются. Так сделано для того, чтобы форматировать HTML красивой "ёлочкой". Чтобы выводить корректно всё, что у вас прилетело из бд, можно использовать `<pre>`. Кроме того не забывайте, что в строках из базы могут прилететь символы имеющие специальное значение в HTML, используйте `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно!

Comment: Только сейчас пришла такая мысль: а можно ли пробелы в html помечать так, как они помечаются в непечатаемых символах MS Word (то есть, точкой в середине высоты строки)? Так они сразу бросаются в глаза...

Comment: @forever_young можно. Для этого надо использовать специальный шрифт в котором пробелы отображаются так точки. Такой шрифт можно сделать самому, заменив символ пробела на точку в каком-нибудь редакторе шрифтов. Менее хлопотный способ подсветить пробелы -- это подчеркнуть текст (`text-decoration: underline`)

Comment: Спасибо  еще раз, +1